# Importing account settings via file to Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

We manage 100's of users exchange email accounts. The configuration of outlook is a little more complicated as our mail supplier requires more settings to be changed, servers to be manually entered for the HTTP proxy etc.

We would like to save time by creating files which can import the mail settings.

I have done this years ago importing mail settings for IMAP and POP3, but I no longer remember the filetype which Outlook supports to do this.

Is this possible to do with Outlook Exchange accounts?

Answer (score 0):

These are Outlook Profile Customization (.PRF) files. Here is the TechNet article on this matter:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179062(v=office.14).aspx

You can either edit them manually or use [Office Customization Tool (OCT)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179097.aspx) to export existing profiles.